# Can Project Home variable be used to save default outputs of QGIS graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, directory

Is it possible to use the @project_home variable in QGIS to set a default file path location for an output in the graphical modeler?

Ideally I would like the default to be the project home folder which contains a sub folder called Shapefiles and then the file name to be the output parameter name from the model.

> @project_home/Shapefiles/[Model output parameter name]

Comment: I would think there are no direct file outputs in the modeler There are just outputs with a name. If you want to write the output in a file you need to define it when running the model. Maybe translating the model to a python script lets you write the output always to a file.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca thank you, I thought this might be the case. It would be a nice feature so I might submit a feature request.